# Can I create a virtual Bluetooth headset to manipulate call stream?

Tags: android, bluetooth, call

I'm creating an app that interacts with the phone stream, and I'm wondering if this is a reasonable workaround to be able to play audio into the call stream

I know that it isn't directly possible using the API, but is it possible to create a fake Bluetooth device that has a virtual input? I figure it is a similar problem to not being able to answer calls via the API, but you can create a virtual Bluetooth device that sends a fake keypress, which picks up the call.

Or is there another workaround that may do what I'm trying to accomplish?

Comment: If you wanted to mix music with microphone input you'd probably run into a lot of problems with this approach. Trying to record from the phone's internal mic might not work since it probably would select your virtual BTHF as the input no matter which AudioSource you specified. Even if you did manage to record from the internal mic you'd now have a fairly large latency in the uplink, and you'd most likely screw up the normal voice call audio processing (echo cancellation, sidetone, etc).

Comment: Actually I'm not worried about having the audio file playing in sync with anything, it isn't important for what I'm trying to accomplish. If I can get sound to play from a file into the call stream, that is all that I'm looking for

Comment: @Moez, did you managed to get any success?